# S60 toolchain for Qt SDK

Tags: qt, symbian

The QtSDK docs say:

> the offline installer does not contain the Maemo tool chain or 
>   tool chains for some Symbian devices, such as S60 5th Edition Qt 4.7.3

And the online installer, that only has those toolchains, is useless now, that qt.nokia.com is dead. So is the S60 toolchain now lost forever, and there's no one in the whole universe who has it installed? Because wherever I search, there's only the .sis file available, that installs the thing on the phone itself. While my goal is to build apps for S60 in the first place.

Comment: You can still get the source and build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check my blog, we collected as much as possible:

http://n8delight.blogspot.de/2014/05/for-developers-re-up-of-symbian.html

Edit:

The QtSDK v1.2.1 offline installer includes the s60v5 SDK.
It's linked and mirrored in our archive :)

I am not sure about Maemo, maybe it's part of Qt SDK 1.1.2 offline installer.

Comment: Thanks for the mirror, it seems to have the needed stuff. But there's a question: can Qt Simulator run j2me, or only C++?

Comment: Only Qt related stuff :-\ For real J2ME Symbian development and testing you need a classic Symbian SDK (s60v3/s60v5/S^3 or Belle).

Answer (score 0):

There is archive for old Qt Creators here: http://download.qt.io/archive/qtcreator/ and for SDK here: http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/ so if you have all the necessary libraries installed in your phone, I think you should be able to build Symbian binaries for it.